# Get mem address of a Method's body whose assembly is loaded through Assembly.load

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection, mono.cecil

I have loaded an assembly B into the appdomain of assembly A using Assembly.load().

B has a method named "X" which i need to retrieve its memory address/pointer.

I understand that B is mapped into memory as a single contiguous memory data after assembly.load(). I am able to reach this location using GetHInstance(module). By using RVA offset to reach the code segment for B will not work since B is mapped using raw offset instead.

How do i retrieve a X's memory address from within A?

Comment: I think you are going to need to give a lot more detail on the context, and what you are trying to achieve here if you are going to get any useful responses, especially since various parts of your question (like "B is mapped using [a] raw offset") just don't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

What is the end goal of this?  Do you need a function pointer to pass to unmanaged code?  Because, if so, that's not going to work - the RVA will likely only point to IL code, not native code, which the process can't run.

For the purposes of this demo, I'll assume that the method matches an Action signature (parameterless and returning a void type), is static, and is called SomeMethod on the class FullyQualified.TypeName.  Given an assembly reference "asm" in local scope:

```
Type t = asm.GetType("FullyQualified.TypeName");
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("SomeMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

At this point, if you really want the method body in IL, you can call:

```
MethodBody body = method.GetMethodBody();
```

Or, if you want it in native code, that you can pass to native code, then you can do this:

```
Action action = (Action)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(action);
```

There are other things you need to do if you're looking at an instance method (you'll need to pass in an instance as a second parameter to MethodInfo.CreateDelegate, for example, as well as changing the binding flags).  Given appropriate permissions, you can also access private methods via this mechanism.

Comment: I was not given the Method's metadata token or method's name. just the virtual offset from the start of metadata (.text) section.

I need to retrieve the IL byte content with a given RVA. However, assembly.load() loads the .NET assembly using raw file offset. I need to ensure that my codes will work for both virtual and raw addresses since the assembly could be loaded dynamically into a parent's appdomain or started independently as a standalone. executable.

Comment: I'm sorry to say Ron, but that's one of the most random requirements I've ever heard of.  More to the point, it's an implementation detail.  Even if we could reliably get you that information, it is subject to change across any version of .NET, the loader, etc.  Why in the world would you need this particular piece of info?